# Identify the columns that have the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case

I want to create a new column, in this case "Reiterate" that marks "YES" for the rows that have the same key (Clave) and have less than 7 days between `resolutiondate` and `createddate`, and the column `Massive` have to be "NO". Here is an example of what I want to get.

[image]

I want to try using `lead and lag` formula to sort the dates from lowest to highest, but don't know how to apply it in SQL. Im not really sure if it is possible to do get that column.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Edit.

I used the formula that you suggest and it works! , thanks again for all the help :)

```
SELECT top 100
CF1.STRINGVALUE AS 'ID OT',
jis.created, 
jis.resolutiondate,
IIF(CF3.STRINGVALUE like 'IDR-%','SI','NO') AS 'Massive',
cfo8.customvalue AS 'Solved',
CASE WHEN jis.resolutiondate IS NULL 
     THEN 'NO'
     WHEN LAG(resolutiondate) OVER (PARTITION BY 'ID OT' ORDER BY resolutiondate) >  DATEADD(DAY, -7, resolutiondate)
     AND LAG(CF3.STRINGVALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY 'ID OT' ORDER BY resolutiondate) = 'NO'
     AND LAG(cfo8.customvalue) OVER (PARTITION BY 'ID OT' ORDER BY resolutiondate) = 'NO'
     THEN 'NO'
     ELSE 'YES'
END AS SLA

FROM [DWH].[JIR].[jiraissue] jis
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF1 ON (CF1.issue = jis.id AND CF1.CUSTOMFIELD = 10004)
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF3 ON (CF3.issue = jis.id AND CF3.CUSTOMFIELD = 10032)
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF14 ON (CF14.issue = jis.id AND CF14.CUSTOMFIELD = 10906)
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].customfieldoption cfo8 ON (CF14.customfield = cfo8.customfield AND CF14.stringvalue=CAST(cfo8.id AS CHAR))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when massive = 'SI' then 'NO'
             when lag(resolutiondate) over (partition by key) < 
                  dateadd(-7, day, creationdate
             then 'No'
             else 'Si'
        end) as SLA
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    case 
        when lag(resolutiondate) over(partition by key order by resolutiondate) > dateadd(day, -7, resolutiondate)
            and lag(massive) over(partition by key order by resolutiondate) = 'NO'
        then 'SI'
        else 'NO'
    end as sla
from mytable t
```

This compares the date on the current row to the date on the previous row, and checks the `massive` status on the previous row.

Maybe you want to check the status on the current row rather than on the previous one - that is a bit simpler:

```
select t.*,
    case 
        when lag(resolutiondate) over(partition by key order by resolutiondate) > dateadd(day, -7, resolutiondate)
            and massive = 'NO'
        then 'SI'
        else 'NO'
    end as sla
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this is written it doesn't seem necessary to evaluate the key column.  The resolution dates are the same for each key.  Something like this

```
select t.*,
       case when t.massive='No' and dt.diff<7
            then 'Si'
            else 'No' end SLA
from tTable t
     cross apply (values (datediff(day, created, resolutiondate))) dt(diff);
```